# macOS Zsh can't find installed Spicetify command

Tags: macos, zsh, spotify

I tried downloading [Spicetify](https://spicetify.app) (A terminal app that customizes spotify) on my Mac.

I ran the install command, but after successfully installing it. I tried running `spicetify --help`, but my terminal could not find the command `spicetify`.

Even though I went through my `<username>` folder and found the `.spicetify folder`, probably meaning that it has successfully installed. I diceded to re-install it. Here is the install process:

```
myname@My-MacBook-Air ~ % curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spicetify/spicetify-cli/master/install.sh | sh
FETCHING Version 2.27.0
DOWNLOADING https://github.com/spicetify/spicetify-cli/releases/download/v2.27.0/spicetify-2.27.0-darwin-arm64.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
EXTRACTING /Users/me/.spicetify/spicetify.tar.gz
SETTING EXECUTABLE PERMISSIONS TO /Users/me/.spicetify/spicetify
REMOVING /Users/me/.spicetify/spicetify.tar.gz
spicetify path already set in /Users/me/.zshrc, continuing...

spicetify v2.27.0 was installed successfully to /Users/me/.spicetify
Run 'spicetify --help' to get started
myname@My-MacBook-Air ~ % spicetify --help
zsh: command not found: spicetify
myname@My-MacBook-Air ~ %
```

I belive the source of this problem is in my `.zshrc` file. I remember that I made some changes to it, but don't remember what. This is what it looks like currently:

```
#export PATH="$HOME/Users/me/Desktop/zsh commands:$PATH"
#export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.spicetify
```

Should I un-comment these 2 lines? What do these lines do? (I have no idea how zsh works)

Comment: after uncommenting your suggested line, I tried again and it worked! Do you know what the code does by any chance? I'm a bit confused of why and how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a path issue. Look at this.

> This is what it looks like currently:
>
> ```
> #export PATH="$HOME/Users/me/Desktop/zsh commands:$PATH"
> #export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.spicetify
> ```
>
> Should I un-comment these 2 lines?

I suggest you uncomment the second line (`#export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.spicetify`), close the Terminal, reopen it and try again.

That line appends the `/Users/me/.spicetify` path to the system `$PATH` variable. That `$PATH` environment variable tells the system where to search for binaries when you type them in.

So in this case, you typed `spicetify --help` and it could not find the `spicetify` binary until you added the `/Users/me/.spicetify` to the `$PATH` environment variable. Then by closing the Terminal and reopening it reloaded the `.zshrc` and then you were all set.